# How to I show the bookmarks bar and shortcuts in my Chrome new tab extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

i am creating a custom chrome new tab page. However when my extension is in use. Chrome fails to show the bookmarks bar. But when I disable my simple extension it shows up again. Is there a way to show the bookmarks bar in my new tab chrome extension.

Also it would be nice to show the bookmarklets and shortcuts to frequently visited sites as well.
Any API references are appreciated.

Comment: No, you'll need to read them via chrome.bookmarks API and show as DOM elements yourself.

Comment: @wOxxOm can I just override the newtab page with a content script instead.. basically delete the components i don't need keep the rest . is this feasible. ??

Comment: No, the built-in new tab doesn't allow it.